# join int array to create big array

Tags: java, lambda

I have a condition that I need to create a big array by joining small arrays. I am using the code

```
int[] types = {4,7,9,2,1,7};
int arr[] = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).map(x -> types).collect();
```

I need the copy of `types` that should be the number of size of the list. I can do it with simple loop with the conditions, but is it possible with lambda expressions?

Thanks

Comment: Why not Arrays.asList()?

Comment: I do not think this will even compile. Shouldn't you use `toArray` instead of `collect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
int arr[] = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                     .flatMap(x -> IntStream.of(types))
                     .toArray();
```

This will create an `IntStream` of `list.size()` copies of the `types` array and then collect it to a single array.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I get the error as `The method flatMapToInt((<no type> x) -> {}) is undefined for the type IntStream`

Comment: @vaydesalme my bad, fixed now. I forgot that the original stream was already an `IntStream`.